Draw dashed border/outline around nontransparent part of image on canvas
I'm drawing an image onto a canvas and trying to apply red dashed outline of approximately 2px but end up with solid red outline. The source image is a .png image with top and bottom texts as part of the image as following example.
A Polar Bear with top and bottom text.

I am using following function to generate red outline:
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
export const genOutline = (
  imgSrc
) => {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const refImage = new Image();
  refImage.src = imgSrc;
  refImage.style.width = "max-content";
  refImage.style.height = "max-content";
  refImage.onload = () => {
    //define hight and width of the canvas
    canvas.width = refImage.width + 30;
    canvas.height = refImage.height + 30;

    var dArr = [-1, -1, 0, -1, 1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1], // offset array
      s = 2,  // thickness scale
      i = 0,  // iterator
      x = 5,  // final position
      y = 5;

    // draw images at offsets from the array scaled by s
    for (; i < dArr.length; i += 2) {
      ctx.drawImage(refImage, x + dArr[i] * s, y + dArr[i + 1] * s);
    }

    // fill with color
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-in";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.

    // draw original image in normal mode
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    ctx.drawImage(refImage, x, y);

    canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
      console.log("blob", blob);
      saveAs(blob, "image_outlined.png");
      canvas.remove();
    });
  }
}

But I want to achieve something similar to what is in the following image:
A Girl portrait with top and bottom text and red dashed outline.


You say that you "end up with solid red outline". Can you please show us that code, then we can help you figure out how to get a dotted line instead of solid.

Not at all easy. You need to find an edge pixel and then trace pixel by pixel the outer edge until it returns to the starting pixel, or hits the edge of the canvas. This will give you  a path that you can apply your dashed line to. Use ctx.getImageData to get the pixel data

In your code I do not see you tried anything with dashes...
You can do dashes with setLineDash here are two small examplea


class Shape {
  constructor(x, y, width, height, color, dashes) {
    this.color = color
    this.dashes = dashes 
    this.path = new Path2D();
    this.path.arc(x, y, height / 3, 0, Math.PI, true);
    this.path.rect(x + width / 2, y, -width, height);
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.setLineDash(this.dashes);
    ctx.strokeStyle = this.color;
    ctx.stroke(this.path);
  }
}


var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var shapes = [];
shapes.push(new Shape(30, 30, 50, 50, "blue", [3, 3]));
shapes.push(new Shape(95, 50, 40, 40, "red", [5, 5]));

shapes.forEach((s) => s.draw(ctx));
<canvas id="canvas" width="160" height="160"></canvas>





const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.setLineDash([10,5])

function drawSpiral(x, y, radiusChange, maxRadius) {
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  var a = 0, r = radiusChange;
  while (r < maxRadius) {
    a += 1 / r * Math.PI;
    r = a * radiusChange;
    ctx.lineTo(x + Math.cos(a) * r, y + Math.sin(a) * r);
  }
  ctx.stroke();
}
drawSpiral(80, 80, 4, 80);
<canvas id="canvas" width="160" height="160"></canvas>



The big problem is doing that around the picture outline.
Your solution for outline was to draw images at offsets, that won't do for dashes you really need to get a true outline then draw it with lines
